# HTML parser for python that can keep track location of the tag within HTML document

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I'm parsing HTML pages using python. I need to locate certain tags and measure distance between them in bytes.
I used BeautifulSoup but it has no way of getting the locations of found tag. Is there any python libraries that can do that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post an example about -- what do you mean about "locations" of tags?

Comment: Do you mean you want the character position with the document where each tag begins?

Comment: Yes exatly, the character position with the document where each tag begins

Comment: @user1354033 have you seen my answer? Do update the status of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention of getting the character position of where each tag begins then you can use the following code to do so. I had this from one of my coding challenges to get the position of where a term/tag begins and to count. You can adapt this to fit your needs.

```
import urllib.request

def getTopicCount(topic):
    url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
    contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url+topic).read().encode('utf-8')
    count = 0
    pos = contents.find(topic) #returns when this word was encountered. -1 its not there
    while pos != -1: #returns -1 if not found
        count += 1 
        pos = contents.find(topic, pos+1)#starting posistion in the returned json request
    return count

print(getTopicCount("<div"))
```